# Why my code for login in PHP is not working?

Tags: php, authentication, pdo

I have tried a lot. Still it is not working. Please somebody help me to find issue in this code block. Thank you.

```
$email = htmlspecialchars($_POST["email"]);
$password = $_POST["password"];
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email LIMIT 1");
$stmt->execute(array(':email' => $email));
$row = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
    if (password_verify($password, $row['password'])) {
       echo "Valid";
    } else {
      echo "Invalid";
    }
    $stmt->close();
    $con->close();
}
```

Comment: Where do you fetch the data?

Comment: What doesn't work? Don't expect us to be magicians reading from the glass-ball.

Comment: I would start with `var_dump($row)` and checking for SQL errors and debugging prepared SQL.

Answer (score 1):

try replacing

```
$row = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if($stmt->rowCount() > 0) { ...
```

with

```
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if($row!==FALSE) {...
```

and not sure about colon in $stmt->execute(array('**:email**' => $email));
it maybe not needed there